# Deleting homemade tabs JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website that have homemade tabs hierarchy, and I am currently trying to add a control that allow users to delete a tab. I am using this code :

```
function killPage(jQFrame){
  $(jQFrame).empty();
}
```

`jQFrame` is referring to the tab I want to delete (using `killPage(getElementById(id_of_the_tab))`).
Although, even if the tab is empty, it still displays it:

[Empty tab display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv653.png)

And I can still access it as well !

Here's a copy of the html calling `killPage()` :

```
<div class="article-header">Accueil MySILOG <img class="loading" alt="loading" title="loading" src="<?php echo HTTP_IMG_PATH ?>load.gif"/>
    <a align="right" class="close" onclick="killPage(getElementById('<?php echo $uuid ?>'))"></a>
</div>
```

`$uuid` = id of the tab

[Tab zoomed in to see the close button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naXT0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`jQuery.empty`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) will only clear the node of its contents. You also need to [`jQuery.remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) the node from the DOM.

Using jQuery's `remove` method will perform the same cleaning up as `empty` does, so there's no need to call both functions, a call to `jQuery.remove(node)` is sufficient.